# Javascript syntax using await Promise.all

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am trying to understand the below code/syntax which uses await Promise.all;
How is the array getting assigned from the endpoint response ?

```
const getState = async (code) => {
    try {
      const [
        {data: dataResponse},
        {data: stateDistrictWiseResponse},
        {data: statesDailyResponse},
        {data: stateTestResponse},
        {data: sourcesResponse},
        {data: zonesResponse},
      ] = await Promise.all([
        axios.get('https://example.org/data.json'),
        axios.get('https://example.org/state_district_wise.json'),
        axios.get('https://example.org/states_daily.json'),
        axios.get('https://example.org/state_test_data.json'),
        axios.get('https://example.org/sources_list.json'),
        axios.get('https://example.org/zones.json'),
      ]);      
      console.log(stateTestResponse.states_tested_data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Array destructuring assignment

Comment: What exactly is the thing you cannot understand? Cause there's a lot going on here.

Comment: array + object destructuring

Comment: I am trying to understand how the JSON is finally being getting assigned within that array const []
Not trying to understand Promise.all

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.all` converts an array of promises into an array of results.

`axios.get` returns a promise that, when resolved, returns an object with the shape `{ data: <result goes here>`

Your code is destructuring those objects within the returned array.

Comment: Thanks a lot...We are pretty close. All I am trying to understand is once we get { data: <result goes here>}
then how exactly does it get assigned to the array...

Specifically, if you look at the next line, there is 
console.log(stateTestResponse.states_tested_data)

I am confused as how stateTestResponse gets the value since it is on the right hand side  in the line {data: stateTestResponse}

Comment: That's exactly how destructuring works. Try looking at the MDN documentation for it?